# R - set reference level of factor to NA

Tags: r, r-factor, categorical-data

I have a data.table with factor columns where some values are NA.  I have deliberately included NA as a level of the factors (i.e., `x <- factor(x, exclude=NULL)`, rather than the default behavior of `x <- factor(x, exclude=NA)`) because the NAs are meaningful for my model.  For these factor columns, I wish to `relevel()` the reference level to NA, but I am struggling with the syntax.

```
# silly reproducible example
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(animal = c("turkey","platypus","dolphin"),
            mass_kg = c(8, 2, 200),
            egg_size= c("large","small",NA),
            intelligent=c(0,0,1)
            )
lr <- glm(intelligent ~ mass_kg + egg_size, data=a, family = binomial)
summary(lr) 

# By default, egg_size is converted to a factor with no level for NA
# However, in this case NA is meaningful (since most mammals don't lay eggs)

a[,egg_size:=factor(egg_size, exclude=NULL) ] # exclude=NULL allows an NA level

lr <- glm(intelligent ~ mass_kg + egg_size, data=a, family = binomial)
summary(lr) # Now NA is included in the model, but not as the reference level

a[,levels(egg_size)] # Returns: [1] "large" "small" NA    

a[,egg_size:=relevel(egg_size,ref=NA)]
# Returns:
# Error in relevel.factor(egg_size, ref = NA) : 
#   'ref' must be an existing level
```

What is the correct syntax for `relevel()`, or do I need to use something else?  Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the correct `NA` type, which is `NA_character_`, but that then throws out the `NA`, which is presumably a bug. A workaround is to specify levels directly yourself:

```
# throw out NA's to begin with
egg_size = factor(c("large","small",NA), exclude = NA)

# but then add them back at the beginning
factor(egg_size, c(NA, levels(egg_size)), exclude = NULL)
#[1] large small <NA> 
#Levels: <NA> large small
```

In case you're wondering, `c` converts the `NA` to the correct type, from `logical`.

Comment: Great workaround, thanks.  I had actually tried `NA_character_` and wondered why it dropped the level.